# What is the solution to the mushroom farmer's card game?

Tags: samorost-3

The mushroom farmer says this:

[image]

I have no idea what I'm doing:

[image]

What is the solution?

Comment: what is the card thingy that is hiding?

Answer (score 5):

So I have figured out the general gist of the solution: certain cards interact when placed next to each other. This allows you to place the fisherman next to the pond and get a fish. The cards retain their state as long as they're in play, so you can catch a fish, cook it and provide it to the hungry campers.

Here is the full solution:

> Archer next to small animal, animal next to fire, cooked animal next to campers

> Spearmen, then mammoth, then pond. Dead mammoth next to fire, etc.

> Deer next to mushroom, archer next to tripping deer, deer next to fire etc.

> Fisherman next to mushroom, then next to fire, then next to pond, etc.